# Send a GET request with headers in Haskell

Tags: http, haskell

I would like to send an `HTTP GET` request with an auth header and a custom header in Haskell. I can't seem to find a way to do it - most things seem only to care about headers in `POST` request. Can anyone help me? So in this case I'm trying to send:

```
Authorisation: AUTH_INFO_STRING
custom-header: string
```

To the URL: `someUrl/query?[search_term]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [Wreq](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wreq-0.4.1.0/docs/Network-Wreq.html) library, I believe

```
let opts = defaults & header "Authorisation" .~ ["AUTH_INFO_STRING"] 
                    & header "custom-header" .~ ["string"] 
                    & param  "search_term"   .~ ["my","search"]
getWith opts "http://httpbin.org/someUrl"
```

should do what you want.